# Getting error message on webpage but test cases get passed -using testng with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng

**Driver class:**

```
package com.deere.gmsr;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Driver {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriver openBrowser(String browserName, String url) throws InterruptedException {

        if(browserName.equals("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver=new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get(url);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return driver;

        }else
        if(browserName.equals("IE")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //  driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        return driver;


    }else
    if(browserName.equals("Firefox")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //  driver.get(url);
        Thread.sleep(5000); 
        return driver;
    }
        return driver;

}


    public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        try{
            if(driver == null) {

            PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader(); 
            Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
            openBrowser(properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL"));
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return driver;
    }

    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

**Properties :**

```
package com.deere.gmsr;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesFileReader {

    public Properties getproperty() throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputstream=null;
        Properties properties=new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream("Configuration/config.properties"));
        }catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " +e);
        }

            return properties;
        }


}
```

**Loginpage:**

```
package com.deere.gmsr.page;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPage {

    //  WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    //  this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

    }

    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="username")
    public WebElement usernametexbox;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="-password")
    public WebElement passwordtextbox;

    @FindBy(how=How.ID,using="signin-")
    public WebElement signin;

/*  @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//button[@class='btn btn-primary']")
    public WebElement acceptbutton; */

   public void enter_username(String username) {

    usernametexbox.clear();
    usernametexbox.sendKeys(username);
    usernametexbox.getText();
    }

    public void enter_password(String password) {

        passwordtextbox.clear();
        passwordtextbox.sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickToSigninbutton() {
        signin.click();
    }

/*  public void clickToAcceptbutton() {


    acceptbutton.click();

    } */

public void fill_LoginDetails() {

    enter_username("ggggg");
    enter_password("hhhhh");



    }


}
```

**Logintestcase:**

```
package com.deere.gmsr.testcase;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.deere.gmsr.Driver;
import com.deere.gmsr.page.LoginPage;

public class LoginTestcase {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public LoginPage loginpage=new LoginPage(Driver.getDriver());


@Test
public void enter_LoginDetails() {

    loginpage.fill_LoginDetails();

/*   Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
 driver=BrowserUtility.openBrowser(properties.getProperty("browserName"),properties.getProperty("URL")); */

}


@Test
public void click_on_sign_in_button() {

    loginpage.clickToSigninbutton();

    System.out.println("Sign-In successfully");

}

}
```

**testng xml:**

```
<suite name="GMSR">
    <test name="LoginTest">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.deere.gmsr.testcase.LoginTestcase" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: what error message you are getting on webpage?

Comment: We found some errors. Please review the form and make corrections.-This is the error message and it doesnt click on sign-in button, but test cases passed ------Sign-In successfully
PASSED: click_on_sign_in_button
PASSED: enter_LoginDetails

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

Comment: Then it's error of what you are sending the values in your text boxes in username and password, try to enter correct value may be validations required.

Comment: thanks, but I have used the same webelements in my cucumber framework but it was working perfect there, even I have added a clear method too which will clear the text

Comment: It's the error of `TestData` what you are sending may be in your cucumber framework you was sending correct value.

Comment: Your page object will not work as written.  Why did you comment-out the declaration of the local driver variable and the assignment of it in the class instantiation?  The page object needs to have access to the webdriver, more than just instantiation.

Answer (score 1):

Test case does not fail because it does not include any assertions. As mentioned by @Upkar Singh in the comment - your login test data is not valid, therefore page is showing some kind of error saying that login did not succeed.

If you want the test case to fail, you need to assert that some condition is met (i.e. that some kind of homepage is shown). I do not know how your page looks like but it will be something like this:

```
Assert.assertTrue(some_condition_met);
```

The condition can be something like:

```
driver.getTitle().equals(PAGE_TITLE);
```

But that is specific to webpage you are testing.

Comment: java.lang.AssertionError: loginpage.clickToSigninbutton() expected [true] but found [false]  receiving this message along with at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
 at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:494)
 at org.testng.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:42)
 at com.deere.gmsr.testcase.LoginTestcase.click_on_sign_in_button(LoginTestcase.java:36)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Comment: All I can say, is that the test case is now failing. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Right now I have created two test cases in one class, and one method calling to enter uname & pwd and second method calling sign method, I have changed my code limited to one test and now single method calling uname,pwd and signin & it successfully get login to application, but I dont think its a solution

Comment: Can you update your question with the current code and specify what is the problem and what do you want to achieve?